# Running an embedded exe with its dependencies c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Embedded the following content in my windows application and executed the setup.exe using the code below:

```
 string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "setup.exe");
 File.WriteAllBytes(path, EmbeddedApp2.Properties.Resources.setup);
 Process.Start(path);
```

[image]

When I run the application the installation shield flashes and disappear.

Comment: What happens if you copy the setup.exe to the temp folder and try to run it just "manually"?

Comment: Installation shield flashes and disappear.

Comment: Well, if that's something that shouldn't happen, there you have it: This is not an issue with any programming language. That setup.exe probably depends on some other files to be at the same location. If this really is the road you need to take, try zipping the whole setup folder and have the zip file as a resource. Unzip programmatically to a temp folder and then run setup.exe from there.

Comment: @SimoErkinheimo Thanks for the hint. I did what you said and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try?

```
Process myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.ErrorDialog = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "setup.exe";
myProcess.Start();
```

Comment: What do you mean by stream?

Comment: This technique only works if a file does not have any dependency.